# If I overload the global new operator to use a memory pool to allocate memory, will this overloaded 'new' affect STL memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, allocator

Currently a project in my company overloaded the global new/delete.

I test for some short code, with the global operator new overloaded. And I see the overloaded new is called when I use STL(like vector, etc.) So I want to know will the 'new' suppress the stl allocator and will there be a efficiency dropdown?

Comment: What you are observing (in your implementation) is that the default `std::allocator` is using `operator new` to obtain raw memory.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yeah, the `std::allocator` uses the `operator new`, so is the dafault behavior changed? I want to know whether there is some efficiency change.

Comment: "_...efficiency change..."_ in what?  We don't know what your replacement `operator new` does ? Why have you replaced the default behaviour (what was unsatisfactory)?  Have you created any benchmarks you can share with us?

Comment: Technical point: it's `operator new` that you can replace (not overload). The `new` operator is a keyword; `new object` calls `operator new` to get memory, then constructs the object in that memory.

Comment: When you write your own global `operator new` you are **replacing** the default version. All of your code will use your replacement.

Comment: `std::allocator`, which all C++ standard containers use by default, uses the global `operator new()`, before C++17 and, from C++17, `std::allocator` uses `::operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)`.    Either way, if the global `operator new()` used by `std::allocator` is replaced, it will affect memory allocation used by all standard containers that don't explicitly use a different allocator.

Answer (score 0):

All allocator-aware containers use an instance of the `allocator_type` for dynamic memory management. Actually, they use it indirectly through the `std::allocator_traits` interface, but that is not relevant to the explanation. This means that the overload of the global `operator new` / `operator delete` does not directly affect STL containers, but affects the `std::allocator` as it uses the global `operator new` for the implementation of the `allocate()` and `allocate_at_least()` member functions and uses the global `operator delete` for the implementation of the `deallocate()` member function. Since the STL allocator-aware containers use the `std::allocator` as default allocator, by transitive property, the overload of the global `operator new` / `operator delete` may fall on STL containers.

In order to avoid that, it is necessary to implement a custom allocator and always use it as allocator for STL allocator-aware containers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I want to know whether the overloaded version new will affect the efficiency of STL (memory and time), how can I write a test code and what tools can I use? Say, if I overload new just as `malloc(size)`, will there be a efficiency dropdown?

Comment: @Shihao Sun, the `operator new` and `operator delete` are often respectively implemented with the `malloc` and `free` standard functions. Thus, they often have the same time and memory overhead. If you are interested in improving performance, I would suggest to implement a custom allocator that uses a more specialized approach, such as pool allocator or free tree allocator.

Comment: My company is now using a memory pool, and overloads the global operator new/delete. So I want to figure out how it will affect the STL(since this memory pool is very old code, I want to know can it really reduce the overheads). How can I write a test?

Comment: @Shihao Sun, I think a full explanation on writing a test needs a separate thread. In any case, the best way to understand the effects on STL is simply to compare the allocator benchmarks. Kashio's test looks very good in this regard: https://github.com/Kashio/A5